# chrome.webRequest is undefined in chromium

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am unable to use chrome.webRequest on Chromium Version 25.0.1364.160 Ubuntu 12.10 (25.0.1364.160-0ubuntu0.12.10.1). I get an undefined error when trying to access its methods. It doesn't even load into the chrome namespace. Here is my code and configurations:

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "description": "....",
  "version": "0.9",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "experimental",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["index.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
console.log(chrome,'chrome');
```

output:

```
Object
Event: function (opt_eventName, opt_argSchemas, opt_eventOptions) {
app: Object
appNotifications: Object
bookmarks: Object
browserAction: Object
commands: Object
csi: function () { native function GetCSI(); return GetCSI();}
devtools: Object
extension: Object
i18n: Object
infobars: Object
loadTimes: function () { native function GetLoadTimes(); return GetLoadTimes();}
management: Object
omnibox: Object
pageAction: Object
permissions: Object
runtime: Object
scriptBadge: Object
searchBox: Object
tabs: Object
test: Object
tld: Object
types: Object
windows: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Go into chrome://flags/ and enable Experimental Extension APIs. Relaunch browser.

Comment: The `webRequest` API is not experimental. Why did you request the experimental permission?

Comment: Troubleshooting step. Your comment has nothing to do with the question. Besides, I already figured this out...

Comment: The `chrome.webRequest` API has been available for a long time. The problem you're experiencing is *probably* unrelated to this API. Extensions using the experimental permission are expected to fail (not load at all if installed as a crx file) if experimental APIs are disabled.